# Problems building gcc 5.2.0 with gcc 3.4.6

Tags: gcc, gnu-make, synology

gcc 3.4.6 is the highest native install for gcc on my Synology DS413, so I'm attempting use it to build 5.2.0 from source. The steps I'm using from /root is

```
tar xzf gcc-5.2.0.tar.gz
cd gcc-5.2.0
./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd ..
mkdir objdir
cd objdir
$PWD/../gcc-5.2.0/configure --prefix=$HOME/gcc-5.2.0
make
make install
```

The build appears to go well until towards the end of 'make' which gives these errors at the end of its run:

```
:
:
make[3]: Entering directory `/root/objdir/gmp'
gcc `test -f 'gen-fac_ui.c' || echo '/root/objdir/../gcc-5.2.0/gmp/'`gen-fac_ui.c -o gen-fac_ui
./gen-fac_ui 32 0 >mpz/fac_ui.h || (rm -f mpz/fac_ui.h; exit 1)
gcc `test -f 'gen-fib.c' || echo '/root/objdir/../gcc-5.2.0/gmp/'`gen-fib.c -o gen-fib
./gen-fib header 32 0 >fib_table.h || (rm -f fib_table.h; exit 1)
./gen-fib table 32 0 >mpn/fib_table.c || (rm -f mpn/fib_table.c; exit 1)
gcc `test -f 'gen-bases.c' || echo '/root/objdir/../gcc-5.2.0/gmp/'`gen-bases.c -o gen-bases
/tmp/ccdefY1e.o: In function `generate':
gen-bases.c:(.text+0x28b8): undefined reference to `log'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [gen-bases] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/objdir/gmp'
make[2]: *** [all-stage1-gmp] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/objdir'
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/objdir'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

'make install' then returns

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/objdir'
/bin/ash /root/objdir/../gcc-5.2.0/mkinstalldirs /root/gcc-5.2.0 /root/gcc-5.2.0
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/objdir/fixincludes'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/objdir/fixincludes'
make[1]: *** [install-fixincludes] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/objdir'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

What's making make unhappy? I'm a newb, so may be missing something obvious.

Comment: The problem is with GMP library, which is one of the prerequisites. It seems that old GCC can't build new version of the library. I don't know if this will work, but you can try to build GCC 4 + corresponding GMP using GCC 3, and then build GCC 5 using GCC 4.

Comment: And failing that (since early gcc 4 is largely incompatible with later versions), he might need more than one intermediate compiler.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. Is this documented somewhere? Searching for "prerequisites for GCC" took me to https://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html which only specifies ISO C++98 compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have already IPKG(optware) installed on your diskstation and the compiler there is really old.
But: There is a developer how actualize the optware. Called: Optware new generation.

I have now GCC 5.2.0 running on my DS713+

further information here:
[Optware](http://www.nslu2-linux.org/wiki/Optware/HomePage)
[Optware NG on Github](https://github.com/alllexx88/Optware-ng#description)